# How to write jquery script in OnClick function?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, onclick

Example:

```
<a onclick="popitup('/upload/?path=/'+$("input[name=file]").val(),'')"> </a>
```

Please help to solve this problem.

Comment: Why not make a independent function instead of embedding it in the a tag?

Comment: Learn about unobtrusive javascript:  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Unobtrusive_JavaScript

Answer (score 1):

This is considered a bad practice because it makes it harder to maintain the [javascript](/questions/tagged/javascript) in the future because you will forget you have it inline in the code.

If you have to do this try this...

```
<a onclick="popitup('/upload/?path=/'+$(\"input[name=file]\").val(),'')"> </a>
```

you need to escape the inner [double-quotes](/questions/tagged/double-quotes)

Comment: @dinesh , if my answer worked for you can you [vote up](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up) or [accept](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) it?